# ASP.NET Development Server simulates IIS6 or IIS7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio 2008, when we press Ctrl+F5, the ASP.NET Development Server is launched to simulate a Web Server. I'm wondering what server does it simulate? IIS6 or IIS7? Is it possible to customize what server it simulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't simulate a server as such, it runs on a server based on cassini that is written in .net and has source code available.  I suppose it's more similar to IIS6 in that it does not support the IIS7 integrated pipeline feature.  You can always choose to have VS use II6 or IIS7 if it's installed (depending on whether you have XP or Vista on your DEV PC).

Comment: For what it's worth, XP 32 bit has IIS 5.1.  XP 64 bit has IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it "simulates" either, tbh, it just a web server for local development where IIS is not an option,  based off [Cassini](http://www.asp.net/Downloads/archived/cassini/). More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a question, not an answer:
What are the server differences between IIS6 and II7 that matter to your code?

For ASP.NET development, the web server itself is somewhat ASP.NET neutral.   It forwards the request to the .NET framework, so THAT's the part that matters.

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx

Adding Morgan Cheng's comment into the answer:
There is some difference between IIS6 and IIS7 on how to explain web.config. For example, to customize UrlRouteHandler, according to MSDN. IIS6 and IIS7 are different. Details in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutinghandler.aspx

Comment: IMHO, there is some difference between IIS6 and IIS7 on how to explain web.config.

For example, to customize UrlRouteHandler, according to MSDN. IIS6 and IIS7 are different. Details in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutinghandler.aspx