# ASP .NET and IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

Most of the developers i work with test their web apps by running them from visual studio, and use the built in web server of VS to display the pages. My question is when these apps are deployed to a IIS server would they behave any differently?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103785/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-cassini-instead-of-iis

Comment: Thanks Josh, I am closing this question as a duplicate

Comment: Another one which helps highlight differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282805/asp-net-development-server-simulates-iis6-or-iis7

Comment: No problem nick thanks for closing, and for asking cause I've always wondered about this myself specifically how it differs from IIS7;-)

Comment: @Josh - Thanks for the IIS 6 vs 7 link ! i was looking for an answer to that as well

Answer (score 2):

One area where your app may behave differently is in the area of security. Because the built in web server is effectively running under your identity (i.e. you could be running as an admin user), when you deploy into a production environment life for your app may be very different.

See this article by [Dominick Baier](http://www.leastprivilege.com/default.aspx):

http://www.leastprivilege.com/CassiniConsideredHarmful.aspx